# FFMPEG: AC3 to AAC conversion issues

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, video-conversion, aac

Ok, this one has me scratching my head - and being a n00b isn't helping.

In short, I had a script which I had [perfected to covert MKV video to MP4](https://superuser.com/questions/275193/mkv-to-mp4-transcoding-script-issues).

However, my Ubuntu 10.10 box bit the dust and installed 11.04.

However, my script is now having problems with the following line:

```
ffmpeg -i "${title}".ac3 -acodec libfaac -ab 576k "${title}".aac
```

When it reaches the relevant stage in the script, it returns the error:

```
Unknown encoder 'libfaac'
```

I have tried swapping libfaac for aac, which seems to be installed/recognised by ffmpeg - however that codec is just way too slow.

I have no idea how to either;

1. get libfaac back on my Ubuntu 11.04 install, or
2. find a better codec than AAC to convert the audio.

Any help to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: go to `system/Administration/synaptic`   and   type   `libfaac`   and install it.

if did not work try to install the FULL-FFMPEG from here. The ffmpeg package which comes with Ubuntu is incomplete.

> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095

Comment: Genius. Thank you for pointing me in the direction of that thread, exactly what I was looking for and solved the problem perfectly.